# Swift Filter same location coordinates contained inside an array of objects

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, mapkit

I am receiving from Server, a list of Stores information in an array of objects. Below is a sample -

```
"stores": [
    {            
        "name": “Store 1”,
        "number": "5381",           
        "country": "BELGIE",
        "latLng": [
            50.730614,
            4.231847
        ]

    },
    {            
        "name": "Store 2”,
        "number": "5220",            
        "country": "BELGIE",
        "latLng": [
            50.730614,
            4.231847
        ]

    },
    {            
        "name": "Store 3”,
        "number": "3982”,           
        "country": "BELGIE",
        "latLng": [
            50.7315706,
            4.2303477
        ]

    },
    {           
        "name": "Store 4”,
        "number": "4179",            
        "country": "BELGIE",
        "latLng": [
            50.7262577,
            4.245589
        ]           
    }]
```

**What am I trying?**:
I need to filter out the stores in the array that has same latLng values.

**Why?**
I need to identify these 'same latLng' values and add an offset of some value like 0.001 to the latitude value so that when I show these stores on a map, the stores on same location appear side by side.

[I found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174044/how-to-display-several-mkpinannotation-with-same-latitude-longitude) (answer by **Rob B**) as reference for this approach.

**What I need?**
1. How can I filter with values inside of an object in the array?
I tried something like this inside a for loop -

```
print("\(allStoresInfo.filter({ $0.latLng![0] == $0.latLng![0] }).count)")

This value always returns 4. I know I am missing some basic sense here but need know what it is :-(
```

2. After I filter and add the offset for same values, how do I update my array with these updated values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following method modifies in place the latitude of each store that matches the latitude of another store:

```
allStoresInfo.map{ currentStore in allStoresInfo.filter{$0.latLng![0] == currentStore.latLng![0]}.enumerated().forEach{ index, matchingStore in
        matchingStore.latLng![0] += Double(index)*0.001
    }
}
```

Just a small piece of advice: don't store lat-long values in an array. Either create a struct/class for them or use a tuple to store them.

Comment: Yes, I am using a tuple to store them :-) Thank you for the answer. I am trying this out right away. I loved the way it is written. Used filter before but not very extensively.

Comment: Just a small extension to my question, is it possible to maintain same offset (not the offset value but the appearance) between two locations? i.e. the two locations appear side by side at any zoom level?

Comment: Glad I could help. If you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it. As for the other question, it is possible, but you would need to change the offset value based on the zoom level of the map view, which is a completely different question.

Comment: Accepted the answer. thank you again. True that it is a different question but things (requirements) here changed :D

Zoom, I am not doing anything specific but calculating altitude. Shall I add it in the same question? Would it be SO compliant?

Comment: (mapView.camera.altitude)/1000

Comment: No, you should create a new question for that, since it is a different question with a different problem than this one.

Comment: Ok. I am progressing, hopefully in the right direction. But when I face a problem, I will ask a question then :-)

Comment: I posted a question with what I tried and where I have a problem. Can you look at it once please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45610399/swift-create-offset-for-mkpointannotations-at-same-location-coordinates

Comment: I'll have a look and see if I can help :)