# Swift Offset for MKPointAnnotations for same location coordinates at different altitude range

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have had a problem earlier and that's been [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45588085/swift-filter-same-location-coordinates-contained-inside-an-array-of-objects/45589035#45589035). Further, I have one more question where in I tried an approach and that fails.

I need to show two Annotations on a map, that has same location coordinates. Data comes from a service and I applied a logic to add an offset of 0.0001 to the locations with same latitude. ([SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45588085/swift-filter-same-location-coordinates-contained-inside-an-array-of-objects/45589035#45589035))

Now when I zoom-in/zoom-out, I am calculating the altitude using

```
let updatedRadius = (mapView.camera.altitude)/1000  //in KM
```

And then, I have the following to maintain a constant offset between to annotations (I mean, the annotations to appear side by side at any zoom level)

```
switch updatedRadius {
                    case 0 ... 5:
                        allStoresInfo.map { currentStore in allStoresInfo.filter{$0.latLng![0] == currentStore.latLng![0]}.enumerated().forEach{ index, matchingStore in
                            matchingStore.latLng![0] += Double(index)*0.0001
                            }
                        }
                    case 5 ... 10:
                        allStoresInfo.map { currentStore in allStoresInfo.filter{$0.latLng![0] == currentStore.latLng![0]}.enumerated().forEach{ index, matchingStore in
                            matchingStore.latLng![0] += Double(index)*0.001
                            }
                        }
                    case 10 ... 25:
                        allStoresInfo.map { currentStore in allStoresInfo.filter{$0.latLng![0] == currentStore.latLng![0]}.enumerated().forEach{ index, matchingStore in
                            matchingStore.latLng![0] += Double(index)*0.01
                            }
                        }
                    default:
                        allStoresInfo.map { currentStore in allStoresInfo.filter{$0.latLng![0] == currentStore.latLng![0]}.enumerated().forEach{ index, matchingStore in
                            matchingStore.latLng![0] += Double(index)*0.0001
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Although this code works, it always applies only the 0.0001 offset. Why offset that's applied is 0.0001 always? Need some help please :-)

Comment: Maybe your `switch` always falls through the `default` case. Consider printing `updatedRadius` in the log and then do the math yourself and handle the cases in switch.

Comment: No. It properly goes to the respective switch case.

Comment: Okay. Then is your question ___"why offset that's applied is `0.0001` always?"___

Comment: Yes. And both the pins move far away from each other as I zoom in. and they come closer when I zoom out.

Comment: Well, it's pretty normal. When you see things from a long height above the ground they appear smaller and for the opposite you begin to see them bigger. Same goes with the relative distance between two points. You can't essentially have constant viewing distance between two `MKPointAnnotation`s for different zoom levels.

Comment: Sure, but when I change the offset when the altitude is between 10 to 25 km, why am I not seeing a change in relative distance as 0.001 instead of 0.0001?

Comment: @LohithKorupolu you use the same multiplier for the offset for 3 out of 4 switch cases. You should use the debugger or print the coordinates inside your switch cases to see which case gets activated and what is the actual coordinate after the offset.

Comment: I actually just edited the offset values - the right case as per 'updatedRadius' gets activated but there is no change in distance between annotations

Comment: How are you measuring the distance? With eye prediction or actually calculating distance between them?

Comment: with eye prediction. not actually calculating the distance.

Comment: I see that when the map is first launched, it goes to default case and that offset is applied. When I change the zoom level, although it goes to respective case, the offset is not changing :-(

Comment: The first offset applied is retained throughout. It's not changing as per altitude.

Comment: any clue - anyone?

Comment: @DávidPásztor: did u get a moment/chance to look at this issue again? I am still struggling with it